# Adobe Edge animation on IOS7 not working

Tags: ios, uiwebview, adobe, adobe-edge

I'm trying to implement an Adobe Edge animation inside a `UIWebView` in my IOS7 app. But all I get is a white screen. The same white screen shows up on my iPhone's Safari. The animation runs fine on my laptop's browsers, both Safari and Chrome.

I'm thinking this is an Adobe Edge problem, but here's my IOS code anyway:

```
NSString *filePathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YallaBye_Button2" ofType:@"html"];
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePathString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSURL *aURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathString];
UIWebView *view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
view.delegate = self;
[view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.requestAnimationFrame = window.setTimeout;"];
[view loadHTMLString:html baseURL:aURL];
[self.indicatorForPlans addSubview:view];
```

The indicator works fine without the Adobe Edge html.

I also tried running the `[view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.requestAnimationFrame = window.setTimeout;"];` call inside the `UIWebViewDelegate` method `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` but no luck.

Also, researching the forums, I tried changing my `transform:translateX(0px);` to `-webkit-perspective: 1000; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` but still just a white screen.

What am I missing?